# How to use HttpWebRequest and URL for API calls?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I wrote a dll using HttpClient and tested it. It was working fine and then suddenly stopped working and instead of sending application/json started to send text/plain. In any case, I was advised to use HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient. So I am trying to change my working code to that form. I also asked that question here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e396d8ff-5260-42cd-aa5a-0a220d8bf123/switching-from-httpclient-to-webclient?forum=csharpgeneral

My problem is the following. I have host URL https://someSite.com and I also have two URLs which implement the API I need in the form of url = "/integrationapi//Attraction/Tickets/Validate"

I am not sure how should I create my request variable. I have a separate method which I call before attempting to get a response, e.g.

```html
 private void SetRequestHeaders(string tcHost, string tcUserName, string tcPassword, int tnTimeout)
        {
            request = WebRequest.Create(tcHost) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Host = tcHost;
            request.Headers.Remove("Accept");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            string authorizationKey = Convert.ToBase64String(
             System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                 string.Format("{0}:{1}", tcUserName, tcPassword)));
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authorizationKey);
            request.Timeout = tnTimeout * 1000;
        }
```

Now, how should I use that request variable to call the API Url I need?

Comment: I hope you have provided the API URL in the variable- 'tcHost'. Did you check request.GetResponse() ? It returns you a WebResponse object. You can use that to access everything related to the response you have received.

Comment: No, tcHost is the site's URL. I want to create request variable and then navigate to my actual API urls on that site. This is what is not clear to me. How can I re-use the request variable and go to the URL on a particular site?

Comment: Is your Web API using token authentication? If yes, then you need to obtain the token first. If it is using forms or custom authentication then you need to first get the access granted to the entry point of the Web API.

Comment: Can you please clarify? The website is using Basic Authentication. The method I posted is supposed to allow me to go to the web api. My code was working when I was using HttpClient.

Comment: Can you show me how you are authenticating to the Web API? I guess there is no access restriction in your Web API since you have mentioned that it was already working using HttpClient without going through the authorization? Can you update the question with the HttpClient code which was working for you?

Comment: The site uses basic authorization. I'll re-start my laptop and re-try my original working code now, then post it (although all info is in the MSDN thread I gave a link in my original post)

Comment: So I can not get a proper response anymore using HttpClient or using HttpWebRequest. It worked on Tuesday (with HttpClient) and when I tested last time on Thursday it didn't work anymore. Perhaps the developers changed their API  or what do you think may be the problem? I sent emails to the service API developers, hopefully we'll get to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: It seems you are missing some kind of authentication and authorization steps. As you mentioned, you can get the authentication URL from the API developers. I believe they must have restricted the API to authorized users only. Hope to see some updates from you tomorrow.

Comment: I'm sending proper authorization (Basic) (using UserId and Password). Everything was working before. BTW, if I have host ending with / and API url starting with /, how should I create the full URL? Is there any .NET function that properly concatenates these two?

Comment: I got a response from the developers that the problem was on their end. I now get proper response back using either HttpWebRequest or HttpClient.

Comment: Glad to hear that! You solved the issue on your own :)